# save and display an array of JSON/JS object(name/value pair) value as a comma separated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

```
var obj = {
    aray1:[1,2],
    aray2:["a","b"],
    aray3:["ab","abab"]
};
```

this is the object i have values and i want to store the above array values as as a comma separated string and display as comma separated string on UI.
DB used is `Mongo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `join` method on arrays.

What you can do is `obj.aray1.join(",")` which will return `1,2` that you can display in your UI

Answer (score 0):

As @eddyP23 mentioned, [[].join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will do the job for you.

```js
var obj = {
        aray1:[1,2],
        aray2:["a","b"],
        aray3:["ab","abab"]
};
var result = "";
for(key in obj){
 result += ","+obj[key].join(",")
}
console.log(result.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
        aray1:[1,2],
        aray2:["a","b"],
        aray3:["ab","abab"]
};
var a = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
return obj[key]
})

console.log(a.toString())
```